# Exibir erro do mysqli usando die

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Usava `mysql_query`, como não se utiliza mais estou usando o `MySQLi`.

Com isso fiquei com uma dúvida.

Para exibir o erro da consulta pelo `DIE` é assim que se faz?

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * Fron tabela") or die(mysqli_error();
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Tá faltando um `)` antes do `;`, mas o conceito é o mesmo.

Comment: Troca tbm esse "Fron". A sintaxe SQL correta é "From"

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva, curiosamente, o `fron` ali pode estar de proposito para causar o erro e ver se o `mysqli_error()` funciona :P haha

Comment: hahaah é mesmo pode crer kkk, nem tinha me ligado kkk

Comment: @rray mesmo assim alguém editou e foi aprovado...

Answer (score 6):

Evite misturar o estilo procedural e OO do MySQLi, mantenha coerência

No orientado a objetos a forma correta é através da propriedade [$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela") or die($mysqli->error);
```

No procedural você é obrigado a passar a conexão para a função:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela") or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```