# Devo usar o «or die»?

Tags: php

Vi esta pergunta [Exibir erro do mysqli usando die](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106980/7210) e fiquei a pensar *será que eu devia usar sempre o `or die`* ou é só para quem está a começar para ver que deu problema?

```
$sql = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela" ) or die ( mysqli_error( ) );
```

Comment: Já respondi aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141797/70 (mas como vc falou no assunto, complementei e destaquei a parte relevante lá tambem)

Comment: Tem quem diga que todo script PHP deveria começar com `die()` :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que seja uma má prática herdada de lições básicas da linguagem.

Os primeiros tutoriais do PHP com MySQL, inclusive o manual oficial, mostram exemplos de conexão com o MySQL como o que postou na pergunta:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela" ) or die ( mysqli_error( ) );
```

A fim de simplificar a didática para iniciantes, isso é ensinado dessa forma. Todavia é considerado má prática aplicar isso no "mundo real".

Normalmente usa-se `die` ou `exit` para debugar, criando breakpoints pois esses comandos interrompem a execução no momento em que é invocado.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que tudo vai depender do contexto que você esta trabalhando.
O lado *'ruim'* de usar o `die` é que sua execução vai acabar por ali mesmo. Independente do erro.
Utilizando de outros métodos como `try/catch` você vai ter a oportunidade de trabalhar com `Exception` para personalizar e minimizar as falhar.

```
try {
    $sql = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela" );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$e->getMessage();
    //Aqui você pode redirecionar pra outra página, exibir uma mensagem personalizada ou qualquer coisa melhor do que parar sua aplicação.
}
```

Você ainda pode usar os dois em conjunto em casos específicos:

```
try {
    $sql = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM tabela" );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    try {
       //faça algo como segunda opção
    } catch (Exception $i) {
       die ('Falha: ' . $i->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Acho que tudo vai depender do contexto e do quanto você quer manter seu usuário em sua aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado.
[Fonte](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die)

Comment: Não entendi porque deram -1 a esta resposta.

Comment: O importante é ela ter ajudado você Jorge. Se de alguma forma eu pude te ajudar já fiquei satisfeito. Independente da votação.

Answer (score -2):

Se tu acreditas que a tua aplicação não vai funcionar sem alguma coisa tu deverias jogar uma exceção, mas o `die` funciona também.

Quando tu jogas uma exceção tu podes dar mais informações sobre o erro e tratar de forma mais apropriada, em uma aplicação grande é importante ter um *trace* para te ajudar a dar manutenção no código. No caso quando tu tens muitas classes interagindo entre si fica cada vez mais complicado tu descobrires onde deu erro então as exceções em teoria estão ai para te ajudar.

Answer (score -2):

Eu uso assim, pra ficar bem claro porque o die está sendo usado:

```
        $this->conexao = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        // Checa a conexão
        if ( $this->conexao->connect_errno)
        {
            die( "Falha ao conectar: (" . $this->conexao->connect_errno . ") " . $this->conexao->connect_error);
        }
```

Assim ninguém vai confundir a avaliação curto-circuito.